# Why is my code printing incorrectly to the text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
with open("pool2.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
for line in content:
    line = line.strip().split(' ')
    try:
        line[0] = float(line[0])+24
        line[0] = "%.5f" % line[0]
        line = '    ' + ' '.join(line)
    except:
        pass
with open("pool3.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(content)
```

It should take lines that look like this:

`-0.597976 -6.85293 8.10038`

Into a line that has 24 added to the first number. Like so:

`23.402024 -6.85293 8.10038`

When I use `print` in the code to print the line, the line is correct, but when it prints to the text file, it prints as the original.

The original text file can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4gvgb2zsejz58hn/pool2.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop through an iterable like:

```
for line in content:
    line = ...
```

`line` is a *copy*<sup>1</sup> of the element. So if you modify it, the changes won't affect to `content`.

**What can you do**? You can iterate through indices, so you access directly to the current element:

```
for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = ...
```

---

<sup>1: See @MarkRansom comment.</sup>

Comment: How can I make the changes affect `content`?

Comment: Strictly speaking it isn't a copy until you use the `=` on it. It starts as two references to the same string, but the assignment changes the `line` reference without changing the `content` reference. Your fix is perfect.